# Entering Hungary from India with German student visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I am a student from India studying in Germany. I plan to visit India in a few days. However, I shall be taking the flight to India from Budapest and not Germany. I shall also be coming back to Budapest from India by flight and then travel to Germany by bus/train.

I just wanted to know if there would be issues at the immigration in Budapest. According to my knowledge there should not be a problem since Germany and Hungary are both Schengen countries. However, a confirmation of whether my assumption is correct would be really helpful.

Comment: For completeness, which visa type do you hold?

Comment: @Traveller I have a Type D visa, and residence permit for Germany.

Answer (score 1):

You won't have a problem, just explain what you stated here.

(I presume it is a student visa and not a single entry tourist visa)

Comment: Yes.. It is a student visa. I have a type D visa and residence permit for Germany. So should be OK?